# Как на c# System.Data.SQLite получить все значения стоблбца одним запросом?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

```
SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=cookies.sqlite; Version=3");
db.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT value FROM moz_cookies";
new string[] Arr =   ??????????;
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\xtxt", Arr);
```

Чтоб на выходе получить массив или список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=cookies.sqlite; Version=3");
db.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT value FROM moz_cookies";

var values = new List<string>();

using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        values.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["value"])); 
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\xtxt", values);
}

db.Close(); //или используйте using
```